# Logo verification for duplication

Tags: image, graphical-logo

I hired logo designed from India. I suspect that he just copied already made logo. Is there any way to check is this logo already used in a trademark?

Answer (score 0):

Use services like Google Similar Images Search.

https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1325808?hl=en